# Saving entity causes child entities to be saved too

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using entity framework 5. I want to save an entity without it automatically saving the child entities.

For example, I have an entity `Refund`. This has child entities `List<Voucher>` and `Tourist`. Both `Voucher` and `Tourist` have `Country`. When I save `Refund` all the child entities are saved too. This is okay (although I'd rather do it manually), but when it comes to saving the `Country` it is adding a new country instead of referencing the existing one.

So to get around this I need to set the Id property on the entities, but set the referencing object to null. For example, my `Tourist` has a country Id of 372 for Ireland. I set the countryId to 372, but set the `Tourist.Country` object to null before saving.

Is there a way to configure Entity Framework so that it only saves the specific objects I tell it to save

i.e. `dataContext.Add(refund); dataContext.Save()` only saves the refund and not the child entities.

Comment: EF needs to safeguard the relations between the entities. Your duplicate Country problem is solvable in some other way.

Comment: Yes. The easiest way is to use the foreign key ;-) See this - Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx.